# Personalizar barra de pesquisa?

Tags: url

Como posso fazer isso?

-> http://prntscr.com/ja75k5

Parece ter alguma relação com certificado SSL. Mas não consegui entender e nem achar nada que diga como isso é feito.

Comment: Seria isto? :).

Comment: Sim!! Obrigado. :)